# Share Google File Type via Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to share Google File Type (eg: application/vnd.google-apps.document, application/vnd.google-apps.form, application/vnd.google-apps.presentation, application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet) with the Intent.

My code:

```
private void shareFile(String uri) {
    ContentResolver contentResolve = getContentResolver();
    String mimeType = contentResolve.getType(Uri.parse(uri));
    Intent intentShareFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intentShareFile.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    intentShareFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
            Uri.parse(uri));
    intentShareFile.setType(mimeType);
    intentShareFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hey, check out this file!");

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intentShareFile, "Share File"));
}
```

But when I click an apps to share that file, it doesn't respond and not do anything. Even when I'm trying to upload it on Google Drive, it says that upload is unsuccessful. The share file works fine when I share pdf or docx file.

Apparently, we can't share the Google File Type via Intent. We have to convert the file that has Google File Type to something like Microsoft File Type (application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document, application/msword, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/x-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, or application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation).

Is there any way to convert the URI mimeType so I can share a file that has Google File Type? For the example is changing a file that has application/vnd.google-apps.document as its mimeType to application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document, application/vnd.google-apps.presentation to application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation, and etc. Is there a way to do that so I can share a file that has Google File Type? Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
Intent uploadIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this)
                    .setType(mimeType)
                    .setStream(fileUri)
                    .getIntent()
                    .setPackage("com.google.android.apps.docs");
            startActivity(uploadIntent)
```

Please note `setStream` requires Uri.

Comment: It still says that upload is unsuccessful. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: What type of files are you trying to upload? How much size in MB?

Comment: I'm trying to upload Google Docs file (application/vnd.google-apps.document), the size is 8 KB.

Comment: Have you converted the file to an Uri? Also have you set the right mimeType?

Comment: I got the Uri from ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT and I've already set the right mimeType.